# Configuring Sencha's Rest Proxy not to send model's ID on a POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sencha-touch-2

I have a simple Sencha Touch 2.1 model class:

```
Ext.define('App.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'number', defaultValue: 0 },
            { name: 'first', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'last', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lastUpdated', type: 'auto' }
        ]
    },
    fullName: function () {
        var d = this.data,
            names = [d.first, d.last];
        return names.join(" ");
    }
});
```

A collection of these models is in a store that I've configured to use sencha's Rest Proxy.  When I add a new model to the store, and call the *Sync* method on the store, the new model is posted to a ASP.NET WebAPI **Users** controller and the following action is hit:

```
    // POST api/Default1
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)
    {
        // this is a new user -- get rid of the ID
        user.Id = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the a string is being sent as the ID for the model, so it's not passing the *ModelState.IsValid* check on the controller.  This is what's actually getting sent up:

```
{"id":"ext-record-5","first":"c","last":"d","email":"e","lastUpdated":null}
```

Any idea why the id field is being set to a string?  Also, any idea how I can tell the *post* action in the **Users** controller not to validate the id field (as it should be handling creating a new item, it makes sense for the server to create the ID for the new item, not the client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/21/an-app-in-an-afternoon-sencha-touch-and-stackmob/) helped me figure it out.  The updated model should be:

```
Ext.define('App.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'auto', persist: false },
            { name: 'first', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'last', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lastUpdated', type: 'auto' }
        ],
    },
    fullName: function () {
        var d = this.data,
            names = [d.first, d.last];
        return names.join(" ");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try setting the idProperty to id, even though you shouldn't have to? I found in the past this would resolve my issue. Now I stick to idProperty fields that don't have a name of 'id' to avoid any confusion.

Comment: yeah, I did.  It still seems like I need to not persist the ID since MVC WebAPI tries to convert the json object into a typed object before it even hits the controller.  So instead I just use the location that the model was PUT to (for updates), such as user/1, to set the id of the user in the controller after it's already made it through validation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set idProperty on the model. The field for id should also be set to type auto. See documentation [here.](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  A couple things:

I see the idProperty defaults to id, which is one of the fields I have in the model.  So I don't think I need to add the idProperty config option.  I did change the type to auto, but the id property's still getting sent up to the server and failing model validation.  If I'm missing something could you post how you'd suggest reworking the model please?